# What could be the problem with data when the R does not work out the code?

Tags: r

I have a problem with R running my code. For one dataset it works out well, but the other one it does not. I leave it for hours and it does not complete the run. I got the data exporting from GIS, and I am supposed to get GLM and this is my part of code:

```
mod.lidar <- glm(DAM ~ ASPECT + VCC, data = LiDAR.cal, family = binomial, 
               na.action=na.pass)

summary(mod.lidar)
```

What could be the reason behind which R does not compute this code for one dataset but does for others?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Is there a warning or error message? What does it say?

Comment: Well the model does not work out, I leave it for long time thinking it might need more time but it does not work out. I have the exact same code for different dataset and it works in a second. I really have no idea what could be the problem. My friends tried to run on their computers but it gives same thing back...

Comment: Is there anything noticeably ifferent about the data? Is it bigger than your other data? Lots more or less missing values? All the columns the same classes? How long have you waited? 5 minutes? 1 hour? More? You could try running with the argument `control = list(trace = TRUE)` to get some sense of what it happening...

Comment: Data is different in a way that it has different variables, but both are extracted from GIS in order to be used in R. Both have 7615 rows. I waited for 2 hours.

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data. `dput(LiDAR.cal[1:20, c("DAM", "ASPECT", "VCC")])` will give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 20 rows, something to work with.

Comment: (DAM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), ASPECT = c("38,756378", "53,097176", "239,99295", 
"234,40976", "304,550812", "3,244283", "198,148407", "332,774994", 
"82,614586", "37,320454", "18,072592", "186,218643", "98,539825", 
"111,069183", "16,509119"), VCC = c("0,585938", "0,84375", "0,988281", 
"0,168442", "0,757812", "0,835938", "0,820312", "0,980253", "0,933594", 
"0,4576", "0,693117", "0,965285", "0,954221", "0,128928", "0,949219"
)), row.names = c(1023L, 1410L, 2834L, 265L, 961L, 2003L, 1832L, 
2954L, 2419L, 2708L, 1736L, 1512L, 818L, 3417L, 385L)

Comment: That is first 15 rows as 20 was too long for here to be pasted.

Comment: Please edit it into your question rather than putting it in comments. And make sure you get the whole thing, it should start with `structure(...`

Comment: At a glance, however, it looks like your `ASPECT` and `VCC` columns are `character` class (notice the quotes around them). They should probably be numeric. This may have something to do with either you import or export processes, but hard to say with this little info.

Comment: If I would reclass those into numeric it should work? Thank you.

Comment: I really can't tell if that's you're only problem, but it might be.